# draw OpenGL background in QtQuick by Context Id

Tags: qt, opengl, qtquick2

I have a nice game, which render OpenGL by context ID and i have a nice Qt example "Scene Graph", which render OpenGL by QOpenGLShaderProgram.
How can i draw OpenGL background in Qt Quick by passing GL Context ID to the game render manager?